# Angular project with expressJS on backend doesn't work after adding SSL certificate to angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ssl, mean-stack

I have a web app that consists of 2 parts (Angular for the frontend on Hostgator and ExpressJS on the backend on AWS).
[My CORS configuration is enabled on the backend] everything is working fine until I had the SSL certificate from Hostgator, requests give me this error

```
ov {headers: Yb, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", URL: (backendurl), ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://smarketingbackend-env.eba-rkkgwymj.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/categories", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
path: []
returnValue: true
srcElement: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "(backendurl)", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
target: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "(backendurl)", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
timeStamp: 36201.97499999995
total: 0
type: "error"
__proto__: ProgressEvent
headers: Yb
headers: Map(0) {}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure response for (backendurl): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url
```

I found A LOT of questions regarding this issue and most of the solutions are about CORS configuration. My CORS configuration is enabled, here it is...

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept , Authorization ,X-Auth-Token ,Access-Control-Allow-Headers ,affId "
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

what is the issue here?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

pretty much just a guess, but in your URL `"http://smarketingbackend-env.eba-rkkgwymj.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/categories"` there is `http` instead of `https`. Can you try swapping that out?

Also you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors as a cors middleware instead of providing your own - there might be some ceveats this plugins handles correctly.

Comment: switch HTTP to https on the backend link? is tried that but I didn't get any response